# Skype Will Not Send Messagees

Tags: skype

I've just installed skype:i386 and every time I try so send a message to people, a little yellow triangle with an exclamation point appears that indicates that the message has not sent. Has this happened to anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the latest version of Skype? Is your internet workibg? Skype on Linux is buggy for me. Use the [web version of Skype](http://www.live.com) instead. After you have logged in, click the Skype icon on the top right.